# How can I return an integer from a dao function?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, oracle10g, dao

In a servlet program I created a DAO class containing a function ,which I wish to return a particular value generated by executing an Oracle query.I tried something like:

```
public int timeofdayafternoonthsmon(Getset g) throws ClassNotFoundException, SQLException {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Connection con=Dbconnection.getConnection();
    String userid=g.getuserid();
    PreparedStatement pstmt=con.prepareStatement("select count(timeofday) from mealdb where timeofday=? and userid=?");
    pstmt.setString(1,"Afternoon");
    pstmt.setString(2,userid);
    int no=pstmt.executeUpdate();
    System.out.println(""+no);
    return no;
}
```

But the problem is it is returning 1 as (I guess) success. But I want it to return the result of executing this query.

Comment: I guess there is another function other than executeupdate which can serve my reason.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
public int timeofdayafternoonthsmon(Getset g) throws ClassNotFoundException, SQLException {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Connection con=Dbconnection.getConnection();
    String userid=g.getuserid();
    PreparedStatement pstmt=con.prepareStatement("select count(timeofday) from mealdb where timeofday=? and userid=?");
    pstmt.setString(1,"Afternoon");
    pstmt.setString(2,userid);

    // execute a query, not an update statement and fetch the result set
    ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery();
    // position to the first result, there must be one since count(timeofday) returns at least 0
    rs.next();

    System.out.println(""+rs.getInt(1));
    return rs.getInt(1);
}
```

Comment: In this regard @Boris Pavlović I would like to clear a doubt as when to use update and when to use a query?